# Proof for the limit $\lim_{x\to 3}(2x-1)=5$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am looking for verification on the proof of the above limit by using the following definition:$$\forall\epsilon>0\space\exists\delta>0\space\text{s.t}\space 0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$
This is my working:
$$|(2x-1)-5|=|2x-6|=2|x-3|<\epsilon\\|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\delta\\0<|x-3|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\|2x-6|<\epsilon\Longrightarrow|(2x-1)-5|<\epsilon\quad\blacksquare$$
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Amendment: The definition of the limit I used was not suitable for this question, this has now been corrected and hopefully now makes sense, apologies.

Comment: You're using the wrong $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit. The one you have is for the convergence of a sequence (the $N$ refers to the $N$th element of a sequence). The one you want to use says that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there's a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$, where $a$ is the value $x$ approaches in the limit, and $L$ is the limit.

Comment: @AmaanM I am aware that this definition is conventionally used for convergence of sequences, however, this is the definition that I must use, regardless of it being an unorthodox approach.

Comment: No, the "definition" is not relevant here.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, the two statements aren't related to each other. Let's say I choose $\varepsilon = 2$. Then based on your proof, $N=4$ and the statement should be true for $n=5$. How can I use $n=5$ to confirm that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Moderately *off-topic*: alternative approach: If $f(x)$ is a continuous function everywhere in a neighborhood around $x_0$, then the $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$.  $f(x) = (2x - 1)$ is known to be a continuous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edited proof is correct you have shown that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a delta $>0$ namely,$\epsilon/2$, as $|x-3|<\epsilon/2$ indeed implies that $|2x-1-5|<\epsilon$. There also a typo in the first line $-2$ should be replaced by $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction!

Comment: @awgya if this answers your q then please accept this answer